# How to limit the number of frames ffprobe interprets?

Tags: ffprobe

I have this command

```
ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v  -print_format json -i c:\test.mpg
```

However, it prints off all the frame info. Is there anyway I can limit ffprobe to just look at the first 10 frames? Thanks

B

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-read_intervals` will do the trick. e.g. `%+2` is to read first 2 sec, `%+#2` to read 2 frames.

For example: `-read_intervals "%+2"`

Comment: misleading option name, not quite explained in `ffprobe -h`, but it actually does work to only read the first x seconds from the input file.